# Using Sed to Delete multiple lines using a file with patterns

Tags: sed, raspberry-pi

I am currently using sed to delete lines and subsequent line with various patterns from a file using the following the following code:

```
sed -i -e"/String1/,+1d" -e"/String2/,+1d," filename.txt
```

Works very well however I have a lot of patterns which vary from time to time.

Is it possible to put all patterns in another text file and make sed to delete all entries for patterns found in such file ?

Thanks

Comment: `/String2/,+d,` you sure this is not a typo?

Comment: you could approximate it (slightly inefficiently) with: `xargs -I@ sed -i -e "/@/,+1d" filename.txt <patternfile`

Comment: How do I format the pattern file ? Do I simply put each pattern on a separate line ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]++;next} {for (i in a) if ($0~i) f=2} --f<0' list yourfile
```

- `NR==FNR {a[$0]++;next}` store the list of lines to remove for file list in array `a`
- `for (i in a)`  for every line, loop through all lines in list
- `if ($0~i) f=2` if trigger line is found, set flag `f` to `2`
- `--f<0` decrease flag `f` by one and test if it less than `0`, if yes, print the line.

---

example

```
cat yourfile
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
eleven
```

```
cat list
three
eight
```

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]++;next} {for (i in a) if ($0~i) f=2} --f<0' list yourfile
one
two
five
six
seven
ten
eleven
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the question what is desired but just to note that this code treats patterns as regex and not as fixed strings. If fixed strings are expected then regex special characters may cause unintended output. eg. `Hello?` will also delete lines containing just `Hell`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to stick with `sed` - at all cost, and being creative :-)

Consider using `sed` itself to generate the `sed` script that will perform the substitutions, based on the patterns file.

Important to note that this is solution will process each input file with one-pass, making it possible to use on large files/many patterns.

Proposed Solution:

```
sed -i -e "$(sed  -e '/\//d;s/^/\//;s/$/\/,+1d/' < patterns.txt)" filename.txt
```

The embedded `sed` program (`sed  -e '/\//d;s/^/\//;s/$/\/,+1d/ ...`) will convert the patterns.txt to a small sed script:

```
pattern.txt:
three
eight
foo/bar

Output: (noticed foo/bar ignored - contains '/')
/three/,+1d
/eight/,+1d
```

Notes, Limitations, etc:

One limit (of above implementation) is the delimiter, code remove any pattern with '/' to simplify generation of `sed` script, and to avoid potential injection. Possible to work around this limitation and allow for alternate delimiter (by escaping special characters in the pattern, or leveraging the '\%' addresses). May need additional testing.

Code assumes that the patterns are valid RE.